# Does this `if` condition ever runs?

Tags: python, django, if-statement

I am reading some codes and I am confused here:

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    # compressed

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

        session_key = 'viewed_topic_{}'.format(self.topic.pk)  # <-- here
        if not self.request.session.get(session_key, False):
            self.topic.views += 1
            self.topic.save()
            self.request.session[session_key] = True           # <-- until here

        kwargs['topic'] = self.topic
        return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

so the `if` condition checks that if there is no session with that key then increment `self.topics.view` by one.

I am confused here because whenever a user log in to the website their session will be created automatically and there are zero chances for being no session unless a user doesn't log in to the website. (Please notice that this project doesn't allow unauthenticated users to view the home page, sign in is a must.)
Is this `if` condition will ever be executed?

Comment: put `print(...)` inside `if` and test it with different settings. You will see if `print()` can be reached.

Comment: also put a different print statement right before the if statement to check if it reaches the if statement to begin with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`session_key = 'viewed_topic_{}'.format(self.topic.pk)` the line indicates to post/topic specific session key.
`if not self.request.session.get(session_key, False):` this line checks if the key is available on the session. If not simply adding the key into the session.
**Note:** This is not the login session key. So, don't be confused with the login session key.

Answer (score 1):

The `if` **condition** will be executed(expect there's an exception before). The `if` **block** will be executed depending on the condition.

If the condition is considered true depends on if the key **for that topic id** is not set. This should be true on the 1nd request for that topic ID and false for any later request in the same session. It might be different if other code sets that key or an exception is raised.

BTW You could just use:

```
if session_key not in self.request.session:
```

That would also be more readable.

Comment: Thank you brother, that if condition is great to replace it with this one